# Writing a shell extension (IContextMenu) in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

I'd like to add a group in Windows Explorer's context menu that works like 7Zip's:

[image]

I know there's the shortcut of using eg. [FastExplorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Fast-Explorer.shtml), but I'd like to avoid depending on a third-party tool (besides, FE happens to be deadware).

Google seems to say that this is done through a COM DLL that implements the IContextMenu interface, but the examples I found were all done in C# or VC++.

Before I investigate further, can VB.Net gurus tell me if this can be done in VB.Net, or only C#/VC++ will do?

Thank you.

---

Edit : Does someone know of a third-party solution so that this can be done without requiring an upgrade to .Net 4?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/Jialiang/archive/2010/09/16/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-.net-4---part-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I find it odd that we had to wait for .Net 4 to be able to write shell extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: if it is doable in C#, then it is doable in VB.Net.